# how to put html code into wordpress theme

Tags: html, wordpress

I've been running my own blogger website from sometime and now I thought might be the time of some changes. 
I'm also a website designer. TBH I suck at PHP but I'm good at html. I have designed a Home page for my site and I Want to put it to my website. But the problem is that the site is running on WordPress theme.
So, is there a way that I somehow put my html coding of Home Page into the theme and the rest remains the same(I mean the rest of the pages).

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you want to modify the theme, you will have to create a child theme because if the Theme has an update, you will lose your modification.

Create a child theme is not very difficult and the Codex tutorial is not complicated : https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Hope i answered correctly. If not, tell me why.